# Backup Exec: How to restore Sharepoint content database to filesystem?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, backupexec

I have a problem with Backup Exec 2010 and a Sharepoint 2007 site.
I wanted to restore some deleted files from a documentlibrary with Backup Exec. However this was only partial successfully. For some files i get the error V-79-57344-33938. For unknown reasons those documents were not restored.

To workaround this, i want to restore the contentdatabase manually to the filesystem to create a new web application on a different server to get access to the files.

How can i do this with Backup Exec in a save way?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution for my problem.
The contentdatabase lied in a backupfolder and was directy accessible from the filesystem.
I could then attach the mdf and extract the necessary files by using this: http://blog.krichie.com/2008/07/06/exporting-site-content-from-a-sharepoint-content-database-for-recovery-purposes/